# Access Lua variables in userdata from the C api

Tags: c, lua, lua-userdata

I am working on a project written in C++ which uses Lua as a scripting language.
In order to facilitate debugging we implemented a network debugger which receives Lua code, runs it, encodes the return values in Json and sends that string back.

I managed to implement that for tables, but now I am stuck with variables stored in userdata.
E.g. I have this Lua code:

```
Elements.Avatar.testVar = 5

Elements.testVar = 15

return Elements    

// result
{
  "result0": "{Application:userdata; Avatar:userdata; Physics:userdata; testVar:15; }"
}
```

`Application`, `Avatar` and `Physics` are objects that have been created in C++. The two `testVars` however have been created in the script above.
`Elements` is a table, so I can list all elements, but `Avatar.testVar` seems to be hidden because `Avatar` is a `LUA_TUSERDATA`.

Does anyone have an idea how I can detect variables that have been added to userdata in Lua?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "variable stored in userdata", At least, not as far as Lua is concerned. From Lua's perspective, userdata is a giant black box. All `Avatar.testVar = 5` does is call the metamethod `__newindex` in `Avatar` with the string `testVar` and the new value `15`. How your C++ metamethod (because only C++ code can put metamethods on userdata) interprets this is *entirely* up to your code.

So it can't be done from Lua. Your code will need to provide debugging hooks. Lua 5.2 allows you to implement the `__pairs` and `__ipairs` metamethods, which the `pairs` and `ipairs` functions can use to iterate over your values. Outside of that, you're on your own for querying what does and doesn't exist in a userdata.

Comment: Ok, that's very helpful. I am trying to list these values from the C++ side, so that's not a problem. I am using OOLUA to make implementing lua easier and that led me to assume that the option to store values alongside a userdata object was intrinsic to the language.
So that means I have to check the binding code provided by OOLUA to find out how my Avatar.testVar is stored?

Comment: @user2626359: Well, presumably, `testVar` is the name of a C++ variable in whatever C++ class you exposed with OOLUA, yes?